# Try & Except, maneira correta

Tags: python, sintaxe

A maneira correta de usar o `try` e `except` no *Python* é como?

```
try:
  variavel = funcao()
except:
  return 'error'
```

Ou eu faço:

`variavel = funcao()` e depois eu trato, dessa forma

```
variavel = funcao()

try:
 return variavel
except:
 return 'error'
```

Tanto faz? Sou iniciante no Python, e no PHP nunca usei `try` e `catch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Primeiro o correto é nunca usar um `except` sem nada - em Python 3 (que é o que você deveria estar usando - Python 2 é incompatível e é uma linguagem no limite pra sair de linha -use Python 3), "except" vazio é erro de sintaxe.

Mesmo o `except Exception` - que é uma exceção que 'pega tudo' deve ser evitado,a não ser que no bloco de tratamento de erro esteja incluído uma forma de registrar o erro para análise posterior.

A forma correta é: ter a menor quantidade de código possível dentro do bloco `try`, e ter as exceções mais específicas possível no Except. A ideia nunca é "fingir que não viu o erro" - e sim, impedir que o programa pare dentro de uma situação que já estava prevista e que não depende do programa: um timeout de rede, uma resposta de indisponível de um servidor, um arquivo protegido contra escrita, uma conta feita com números providos pelo usuário que chega numa divisão por zero, etc...

E por fim, quanto a sua pergunta específica - não tem *tanta* importância assim, mas é melhor você manter menos pontos de `return` dentro de uma função, por que fica mais fácil entender o que está acontecendo para debugar e dar manutenção -

então:

```
try:
    resultado = funcao()
except ValueError:
    resultado = "erro"

return resultado
```

Note como o ideal é ter exceções específicas-  se dentro da função acabar a memória disponível para o processo, isso dá um `MemoryError` e o programa para. Quando o programa para, o traceback vai dizer onde ocorreu o erro, e é só ir lá e corrigir o trecho que está criando um objeto maior do que é possíbel. Se fosse um `Except` genérico, o desenvolvedor acharia que era um `ValueError`, que poderia acontecer mesmo, e ia ficar horas em cima disso tentando achar o problema.

Comment: Ok, acabei de acordar, tô lesado, então é bom evitar o uso de retorno dentro do except e sim atribuir algo a variável? O correto seria tratar o erro fora do bloco `try`? Ahhh, eu estou usando python 3

Comment: em Python 3, `except:` sem um nome de exceção da erro de sintaxe. 
sim - a sugestão é deixar um único `return` na função - mas isso não é regra. Há casos em que o contrário é preferível - tem que usar o bom senso. Eu gosto de usar mais de um return quando a  tarefa principal da função depende de vários condicionais - então cada coisa que "falha" no caminho, já coloco um `return`  - aí no final da função é garantido que está tudo certo, os dados limpos, e ela pode fazer a ação principal dela sem precisar se preocupar com nenhuma condição a mais.

Comment: Opa, vou começar a ter este hábito, valeu jsbueno.